# Does JPA allow EntityListeners to perform JPA operations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

It looks like it should be possible at least for PreCreate [JPA 2.1 Create entity within JPA EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464697/jpa-2-1-create-entity-within-jpa-entitylistener)

What I wanted to do is update `@Transient` data in a managed JPA entity and send the managed JPA entity to Kafka on a `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` event.  The operation is going to do a read from another repository to get one piece of data.

However, when I do anything like that I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on flush.

My workaround right now is to do a JOOQ operation to get the data I need from the other table.

My question specifically is does JPA allow this sort of operation (i.e. this may be a Hibernate bug) or is it actually illegal according to the spec.

Comment: Maybe this part in the spec helps you? The following rules apply to lifecycle callback methods:In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
same persistence context[46].
[47] A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
state of the entity on which it is invoked.

Comment: So the only way is to actually put the data somewhere else and look it up in a non-JPA way.

Comment: Relying on post persist/update seems strange: If the data is coming from JPA, why not populate it upfront when reading in the entity? What do you do if the transaction rolls back?

Comment: Why not to add a boolean field like 'need_kafka_update'  , set it to true on persist and query entities with this field = true in background ?  This is not good idea to directly wire remote call in same transaction as data update - Kafka server could be unavailable and you'll get persist exception with such logic.

Comment: @Chris legacy code... just trying to tweak it a little to get something done.

Comment: @C.Webercan you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @AlexChernyshev good point, but I actually want the entire transaction to fail and rollback if Kafka is down

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano even if so - you'll find that listeners could be called more than once  during persist .. and what next? Push each time to Kafka?

Comment: @AlexChernyshev yes push every change including deletes to kafka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [JPA 2.1 Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) in Chapter 3.5.2 (Lifecycle Callback Methods) certain rules apply. One of them states:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
> same persistence context[46].
> [47] A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
> state of the entity on which it is invoked.

What you try to do, according to the description of your question, seems to violate against this rule.